# HAML - understanding how to layout a page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I am still learning HAML and I have some syntax that I am not clear about.

When I see code like this:

```
-content_for :primary_content do
  .content_container
```

What does the content_for block do and mean? Is that a call to a specific layout? Or is .content_container a class somewhere?

The reason I ask is because I have some links that appear on the page and I am not sure why they appear there.  I wonder if primary_content gets a block of code to render? If so, how do I find or look up this block of code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your HAML is roughly equivalent to the following ERB:

```
<%- content_for :primary_content do %>
    <div class='content_container'></div>
<%- end %>
```

Essentially, "[content_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for) :symbol" defines a named piece of content that will later be included in a layout or something.

`.something` is a [HAML](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html) short-hand way of saying "make me a div which CSS class is `something`".

Answer (score 3):

First off: `content_for` isn't a Haml's feature. It's one of helpers available in Ruby on Rails views. You can use it in ERb too.

This method renders the given block but doesn't output it. To see the result of rendering you must call `= yield :key` where `:key` is the same symbol that was used for `content_for`. To check if content was generated use `content_for? :key`.

[Details](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for)

Answer (score 1):

You use content_for to put content in a placeholder called primary_content located somewhere in your layout.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for-3F